# Updating DotNetNuke image library

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Have written simple file picker control for my dotnetnuke site, because the one that ships with dnn doesn't really do what I need. The file picker uses System.IO for collecting directory information and uploading files to the portals root and subfolders. These images can then be inserted where ever I need them. The problem is images uploaded in this manner don't seem appear appear in the file manager or image manager used by the html/text module.

Is there anyway I can register these files with dnn when I upload them so they will also appear in the html/text image manager?

What would be even better is if there is a way to use the image manager that is built in the html module, outside the module although am not looking to buy a pre-made module.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use the DNN API for uploading files.

As for using the built in Image Manager that you find in the HTML module, that is part of the Telerik Rad Editor. You might be able to dig through the source for the Rad Editor Provider and figure out how to include just that portion into an outside module, though that might technically require a valid Telerik license to do.